# Toggle a checkbox when certain areas are clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I want the checkbox to check/uncheck when clicked directly, or when either of the table cells are clicked that do not have the class valueButton.

Currently they work for the first time each, then they no longer work as the checkbox is not checked/unchecked like it was initially.

Here is my (faulty) code in action with CSS and HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/jynn4/

And here is just the Javascript:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $("td:not('.valueButton')", $(this).parent()).addClass('blueHover');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $("td:not('.item')", $(this).parent()).removeClass('blueHover');
            },
            click: function () {
                $("td:not('.valueButton')", $(this).parent()).toggleClass('blueChecked');

                if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
                    $(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).attr('checked', function() {
                        return !this.checked;
                    });
                }
            }
        }, "tr.item td:not('.valueButton')");

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the console for errors.

There's reference error at

```
if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
```

Because you havent put `event` as the parameter to your

```
click: function ()
```

Code needs to be

```
$(document).on({
mouseenter: function () {
    $("td:not('.valueButton')", $(this).parent()).addClass('blueHover');
},
mouseleave: function () {
    $("td:not('.item')", $(this).parent()).removeClass('blueHover');
},
click: function (event) {
    $("td:not(:eq(1))", $(this).parent()).toggleClass('blueChecked');

    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        if($(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).prop('checked'))
            $(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).prop('checked', false);
        else
            $(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).prop('checked',true);
    }
}
}, "tr.item td:not('.valueButton')");
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jynn4/3/)

---

With function

```
$(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).prop('checked', function(){
  return !$(this).prop("checked");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one. The issue from my original post is still present unfortunately. To replicate it, click 'Red Shirt' three times while observed the state of the checkbox. It will go 'checked' > 'unchecked' > 'unchecked'.

Comment: @cianz cheers. and of course you can use function like you did before. See my last edit